# How can I replace a given -Ldir1 by -Ldir2, in a linking command line generated by cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, software-collections

I have a `CMakeLists.txt`.
I use it for generating a `makefile` with `ccmake`.
Then upon `make`, my sources are compiled ok.
At link time, the command line produced is essentially

```
/opt/rh/devtoolset-6/root/usr/bin/c++ myprog.cc.o -o myprog -Ldir3 -L/opt/rh/devtoolset-3/root/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.9.2 ... -Wl,-rpath,dir4:dir5:/opt/rh/devtoolset-3/root/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.9.2 ...
```

The two spots specifying the search path

```
/opt/rh/devtoolset-3/root/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.9.2
```

should actually point to

```
/opt/rh/devtoolset-6/root/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/6.2.1
```

**How can I fix this?**

---

I have `devtoolset-3` in my system, but I do not know where this search path is set, or how to change it.
I actually expected that to take place automatically after executing

```
scl-devtoolset-6
```

(in my `.bashrc`), the same way the correct version `/opt/rh/devtoolset-6/root/usr/bin/c++` is detected without me doing anything else.

Of course, I get many linking time errors due to version mismatches.

The only place where I see the search path set is in line

```
link_directories(${LIBDIR_MY})
```

in `CMakeLists.txt`, and `LIBDIR_MY` points to `dir3`, which is correctly added in the linking command line.
But I found no place where `.../devtoolset-3/...` is added.

Possible origins of `-L`:

1. `link_directories` in `CMakeLists.txt`: checked.
2. `target_link_libraries`: Where? What is the expected file name pattern to look for?
3. `link_libraries`: Where? What is the expected file name pattern to look for?
4. `CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH`: Checked. It is not set.
5. A `find_package` command: See below
6. Somewhere else?

This [How do I add a library path in cmake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28597351/how-do-i-add-a-library-path-in-cmake) does not add to my question.

---

**Update 1**:

There was in fact a `find_package(mylib)` (actually, with a different name) in `CMakeLists.txt`.
Going to the dir of `mylib` and issuing `find . -name “*” -type f -exec grep /opt/rh/devtoolset-3 {} \;` there were two files that matched:

1. `build/CMakeCache.txt`:
   two occurrences of `devtoolset-3`

   ```
   PETSC_LIBRARIES:STRING=...devtoolset-3...
   FIND_PACKAGE_MESSAGE_DETAILS_PETSc:INTERNAL=[...devtoolset-3...][YES][v()]
   ```

   It appears to me that this stems from file `CMake/cmake-modules/FindPETSc.cmake` (possibly invoked by line `find_package (PETSc REQUIRED)` in `CMakeLists.txt`), which has a line

   ```
   set (PETSC_LIBRARIES ${PETSC_LIBRARIES_ALL} CACHE STRING "PETSc libraries" FORCE)
   ```

   and many prior lines

   ```
   set (PETSC_LIBRARIES_<various terms> ...)
   ```

Notes:
I do not know where in that file `devtoolset-3` is first detected and set.

2. `build/include/summit/mylibConfig.cmake`.
   I still could not track down what made `devtoolset-3` appear here.

Comment: Option `-L` is also produced by `target_link_libraries`/`link_libraries` called with imported target. For answer the question "how to replace -L option" we need to know where this option is originated...

Comment: @Tsyvarev - To track down the possible origin of that `-L` from `target_link_libraries`/`link_libraries`, I could e.g. `find <pattern> -exec grep target_link_libraries {} \;` (very primitive). What is the expected `<pattern>` where I can possibly find it?
Is there a more systematic way of ruling out possible locations of `target_link_libraries`/`link_libraries`?

Comment: I would suggest to check `CMakeCache.txt` (located in the project's build directory) first. The variable, contained given path, is likely related to some 3d-party package you used via `find_package()`. Knowing the variable's prefix may hint about which actual package defines it. BTW, your linker command line should contain linking with a library (`-l` option) to the library, located in the directory specified by `-L` option.

Comment: You might also check your install. `share/cmake-ver/Modules/`

Comment: There was in fact a `find_package` in `CMakeLists.txt`.
Going to the dir of that package and issuing `find . -name “*” -type f -exec grep /opt/rh/devtoolset-3 {} \;` there were two files that matched.

Comment: @Tsyvarev - Please see posted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the culprit.
As hinted at in Update 1 of the OP, the sequence is the following:

1. Line
   `find_package (PETSc REQUIRED)` in file (1)
   `CMakeLists.txt` forced processing file (2)
   `CMake/cmake-modules/FindPETSc.cmake`.
2. Line<sup>*1</sup>
   `petsc_get_variable (PETSC_EXTERNAL_LIB_BASIC petsc_libs_external)` in file (2)
   `CMake/cmake-modules/FindPETSc.cmake` sets a local cmake variable
   `petsc_libs_external` from the value of the variable
   `PETSC_EXTERNAL_LIB_BASIC` read from file (3)
   `~/petsc-3.8.2/lib/petsc/conf/petscvariables`.
3. `PETSC_EXTERNAL_LIB_BASIC` is not set explicitly in file (3)
   `~/petsc-3.8.2/lib/petsc/conf/petscvariables`. Line
   `include ~/petsc-3.8.2/arch-linux2-c-debug/lib/petsc/conf/petscvariables` forces reading file (4)
   `~/petsc-3.8.2/arch-linux2-c-debug/lib/petsc/conf/petscvariables`.
4. Line
   `PETSC_EXTERNAL_LIB_BASIC = ... -Wl,-rpath,/opt/rh/devtoolset-3/root/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.9.2 -L/opt/rh/devtoolset-3/root/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.9.2 -Wl,-rpath,/opt/rh/devtoolset-3/root/usr/lib64 -L/opt/rh/devtoolset-3/root/usr/lib64 -Wl,-rpath,/opt/rh/devtoolset-3/root/usr/lib -L/opt/rh/devtoolset-3/root/usr/lib ...` in file (4)
   `/home/sserebrinsky/petsc-3.8.2/arch-linux2-c-debug/lib/petsc/conf/petscvariables` brings the "undesired" directories into the executed command line.

---

<sup>*1</sup> (`petsc_get_variable` is a macro defined in `FindPETSc.cmake`)