# Compiling QT OPCUA on Windows

Tags: c++, qt, opc-ua

I have a problem when I try to compile [Qt OPCUA](https://github.com/qt/qtopcua) on windows with open62541.

I am following [this tutorial](https://blog.basyskom.com/building-qt-opc-ua-with-open62541/) (Building On Windows - Mingw32)

I cannot seem to specify the path to the header open62541.h and the lib open62541.a even if I did

```
set QTOPCUA_OPEN62541_INCLUDE_PATH=c:\path\to\open62541\build
set QTOPCUA_OPEN62541_LIB_PATH=c:\path\to\open62541\build\bin
```

Note that open62541 is compiled and that I do have the files open62541.h and libopen62541.a (in version 0.3) where they should be.

The error I get is a linker problem : cannot find -lopen62541

I added manually the open62541.h to the project files since it was not working either.

What should I do to specify correctly the path to open62541 please ? Is there an up-to-date documentation ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the path where libopen62541.a is to the library path directory.

If you are using **QMake**, you need to specify add it to the `LIBS` variable prepending the path with a `-L` as follows:

```
LIBS += -L$${PATH_WHERE_LIB_FILE_IS}
```

Take a look on how is done in the [QUaServer](https://github.com/juangburgos/QUaServer/blob/237d7bcfe1e0709a3ddcb41a6f1fb94756d7af9e/src/amalgamation/open62541.pri#L2) project.

If you are using **CMake**, then take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28597351/how-do-i-add-a-library-path-in-cmake) on how to add to the library path directory.

What you are doing with those commands is telling the linker where to find the missing libraries.