# How to add linker directory in cmake?

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake, compilation

I am using clion for my c++ project. The command I need to run is:
`g++ server.cpp -L/usr/lib -lssl -lcrypto -o server`

I have tried:

`SET(GCC_COVERAGE_LINK_FLAGS    "-L/usr/lib -lssl -lcrypto")
add_definitions(${GCC_COVERAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS})`

as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11783932/how-do-i-add-a-linker-or-compile-flag-in-a-cmake-file)

Also tried:

`include_directories(/usr/inc)
link_directories(/usr/lib)
SET(GCC_COVERAGE_LINK_FLAGS    "-lssl -lcrypto")`

mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28597351/how-do-i-add-a-library-path-in-cmake).

Nothing seems to be working. I am new to cmake. Can someone explain a solution and some good tutorial/resource to follow.

Edit: Error that I get is undefined reference to `PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC_SHA1' which is a funciton in openssl/evp.h

Following is run by clion: 
/"path to clion"/clion-2018.3.1/bin/cmake/linux/bin/cmake -S"Path to project" -B"Path to project/cmake-build-debug" --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/server.o.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/server.o.dir/server.cpp.o

Comment: First of all, can you show us the error messages? Secondly, CMake will search all standard locations by default, including `/usr/lib`, so you don't have to add that directory to the search paths. Thirdly, are you sure all of those libraries are properly installed?

Comment: The g++ command works correctly so the libraries should be correctly installed. I have edited with the error.

Comment: where are your target_link_libraries() and target_include_directories() calls? What  arguments are you providing to cmake?

Comment: @Tzalumen I added them in the CMakeLists.txt but that didn't work.

Comment: Try `link_libraries(-lssl -lcrypto)`. Also, you might want to post your `CMakeLists.txt` file (at least the relevant parts): https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @thomas_f That worked!!. Thank you. If you'd like to add it as an answer, I would gladly mark as accepted. Any explanation as to why it works while linked answers don't would be appreciated too.

Comment: I'll leave that to @Tzalumen since he/she was the first to suggest it.Also, `target_link_libraries()` should be used over `link_libraries()`. Glad it worked out!

Comment: Okay, I'll put up an answer.

Comment: [target_link_directories](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_directories.html#command:target_link_directories)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed in comments:

In your target CMakeLists.txt, the one with your

`add_executable (${PROJECT_NAME} ...)`

add a

`target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ssl crypto ...)`

call to attach those library dependencies to your target

Comment: From OPs description I got the impression that [target_link_directories](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_directories.html#command:target_link_directories) was what they were after..

Comment: @JesperJuhl If the `target_link_libraries()` call succeeds, you don't need `target_link_directories()`, that just adds directories to cmake for `target_link_libraries()` to check.