# How to link any DLL to Cmake project

Tags: c++, dll, cmake

Is job in qmake:

```
LIBS+= -L"C:\Program Files\program\any_dll.dll"
```

How to in cmake?

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

project(my_project)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} "main.cpp")
```

Comment: `add_library(bar SHARED/STATIC IMPORTED)` ? Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28597351/how-do-i-add-a-library-path-in-cmake

Comment: @Tsyvarev mylib.so is not anydll.dll. Functionally, it is indeed a duplicate, but from the point of view of the text, these are different issues. I believe that this issue should remain so that it can be found in the search.

Comment: "but from the point of view of the text, these are different issues." - Whatever *static* or *shared*, Linux (`.so`) or Windows (`.dll`), `any_dll.dll` is an **external library** for your CMake project, so the duplicate question has been chosen correctly. "I believe that this issue should remain so that it can be found in the search." - *Duplicate* status by no means marks the question as "bad" or "should be deleted". If someone will find your question useful, he/she still able to upvote it. The only thing which is disabled by *duplicate* status is adding (new) answers for the question.

Comment: BTW, the banner "This question already has an answer here" and its reference are tied to the question post while it is in a *duplicate* status. So there is no needs to repeat reference to the duplicate question in the question post itself. (You may include the reference to other question post if it helps to **understand** your **question**, but I see no reason for it in your case. Note, that "understand a question" doesn't mean "understand how to *resolve* it". On Stack Overflow we don't mix a problems and their possible resolutions in the question post.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If CMake does not now a target (i.e. it is not build by CMake) it assumes it to be a prebuild library.

```
link_directories(
  "C:/Program Files/program"
)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} "main.cpp")

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
  any_dll
)
```