# CMake How to properly include my own headers?

Tags: c++, cmake, ros, catkin

I am working with ros and now I want to write my own unittest. But I am struggling with it. Maybe you have an suggestion for me? Or maybe a solution?

```
my structure:
-catkin_ws
--build
--install
--src
----project1
----CMakeLists.txt
----package.xml
------include
--------prime_tables.h
--------sample1.h
------src
--------sample1.cpp
------tests
--------sample1_unittest.cpp
```

my cmakelist.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(project1)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp rostest rosunit)
find_package(sample1)



catkin_package(
   INCLUDE_DIRS include
   LIBRARIES ${PROJECT_NAME}
   CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp rostest
   DEPENDS  )
include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})


if (CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING)
  catkin_add_gtest(project1 tests/sample1_unittest.cpp)

  add_executable(add_test tests/sample1_unittest.cpp)
  add_library(add include/sample1.h src/sample1.cpp)
  target_link_libraries(add_test ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
  target_link_libraries(add_test gtest)
  target_link_libraries(add_test prime_tables)
  target_link_libraries(add_test sample1)
endif()
```

I receive this error:

```
[87%] Linking CXX exectuable

/usr/bin/ld -lprime_tables cannot find
/usr/bin/ld -lsample1 cannot find
```

What is the problem? You mention it, I am not very familiar with CMake.

Comment: Maybe change your `add_library` to `add_library(sample1 src/sample1.cpp)`.

Comment: [The correct command would be](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28597351/how-do-i-add-a-library-path-in-cmake):
`link_directories(${my_path})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `sample1.cpp` is a library you want and to test and you want to create an executable which links to this library and runs a unit test?

Some basic cmake info:
The first argument of `add_library`, `add_executable` and `target_link_libraries` is the name of the library/executable. So if you specify your linked librarys to this library or executable you have to use this name again.

And look here for more information:
http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/CMakeLists.txt
http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/gtest_configuration.html

My guess is, that you want  a cmake like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(project1)

catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
  LIBRARIES ${PROJECT_NAME}
  CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp rostest
  DEPENDS
)
include_directories(include 
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME}_sample1 
  src/sample1.cpp
)
target_link_libraries(
  ${PROJECT_NAME}_sample1
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
)

if (CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING)
  catkin_add_gtest(${PROJECT_NAME}_test 
    tests/sample1_unittest.cpp
  )
  target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}_test 
    ${PROJECT_NAME}_sample1
    ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
  )
endif()
```