# Eigen3 header file in included directory not found when building with CMake

Tags: cmake, c++17, eigen3

I am trying to build a project using Eigen3 library of headers.
My repo has the following structure

```
Eigen
    Dense
    ...
pricing
    CMakeLists.txt
    options.cpp
    options.h
CMakeLists.txt
main.cpp
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "pricing/options.h"


int main()
{
  fun();
}
```

CMakeLists.cpp:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22.0)

project(my_application VERSION 1.0.0 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

add_executable(quant_finance_app
    main.cpp
)

add_subdirectory(pricing)

target_link_libraries(quant_finance_app pricing_lib)
```

pricing/options.h:

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
 
 
using Eigen::MatrixXd;
 

void fun();
```

pricing/options.cpp:

```
#include "options.h"

 
void fun()
{

  MatrixXd m(2,2);
  m(0,0) = 3;
  m(1,0) = 2.5;
  m(0,1) = -1;
  m(1,1) = m(1,0) + m(0,1);
  std::cout << m << std::endl;

}
```

pricing/CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_library(pricing_lib
options.cpp)

target_include_directories(pricing_lib  PRIVATE ../)
```

I run CMake and I get the following error when compiling "options.cpp" file:

```
fatal error: Eigen/Dense: No such file or directory
    4 | #include <Eigen/Dense>
```

Why can't the compiler find the included headers necessary to create "pricing_lib" library?

**Solution**

The solution is to rewrite the file "pricing/CMakeLists.txt" as follows:

```
add_library(pricing_lib
options.cpp)

target_include_directories(pricing_lib PUBLIC ../)
```

Note that the only difference is that instead of PRIVATE I am using the keyword PUBLIC.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I add a library path in cmake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28597351/how-do-i-add-a-library-path-in-cmake)

Comment: In short: Use `"${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}"` instead of `../`

Comment: Compilation of which **source file** causes the error? `options.cpp` or `main.cpp`? You use PRIVATE keyword in the `target_include_directories` call, so the include directory is added only for source files of target `pricing_lib`, but not for the ones of target `quant_finance_app`.

Comment: @Homer512: Using `../` in the `target_include_directories` is perfectly **valid**. CMake automatically convert this path into the absolute ([documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_include_directories.html)). In opposite, using `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR` could be a problem for the case when given project will be included into other project via `add_subdirectory`.